# SSIS script transformation does not process rows in spite of successfully executing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using a copy of SQL Server Data Tools that comes with SQL Server 2014 Standard.  I currently have a script component working as a transformation.  The component is preceded by a flat file source that capturs identifying records for a search from the SDK being used in the contents of the Script Component.  It is then followed by an OLEDB destination.    Here is a sample of the beginning of the code, the three main methods which I believe exhibit the problem:

```
public String LoanIDs_ProcessInputRow(LoanIDsBuffer Row)
{
    return Row.ID;
}

public List<String> LoanIDs_ProcessInput(LoanIDsBuffer Buffer)
{        
    var LoanIds = new List<string>();
    while (Buffer.NextRow())
    {            
        var loanId = LoanIDs_ProcessInputRow(Buffer).ToString();
        LoanIds.Add(loanId);
    }

    if (Buffer.EndOfRowset())
    {
        return LoanIds;
    }
    return LoanIds;
}

public void LoansBuffer_ProcessOutput(LoanIDsBuffer Buffer)
{
    Session session = new Session();
    ConnectToEncompass(session);      
    LoanReportCursor Loans = session.Reports.OpenReportCursor(GetFields(), GetSearchFilter(LoanIDs_ProcessInput(Buffer)));

    for (int i = 0; i < Loans.Count; i++)
    {
        //actions
    }
}
```

When I execute the package in debug mode or even project-deployed, I get zero error messages, and the rows in the flat file source are processed, however no rows are processed in the script component and afterwards.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHuPp.png)

Could this have to do with me removing the "override" and "void" keywords at the beginning of the methods?  They kept me from adding parameters to the methods to pass values between them, but I do get warning messages that say that the messages would need "override" to correctly identify with their UserComponent counterparts.  Not sure what that means.  This is such a headache and I can't even debug the script through breakpoints!

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to debug your script task's code?

Comment: Johannes, what I see happen is the script window opening briefly, then closing out.  That is exactly the question I am asking.  I can't debug because for some reason the application isn't allowing me to.

Comment: I assume you set a breakpoint. Maybe it is not being reached? Try to set it somewhere at the beginning. Also: You must not rename or change the generated methods' signatures. They are the script task's entry points for your code.

Comment: Another Note: Try to summarize your problem. What do you want to do? Hint: The data flow transformation script task can process input and output data in a synchronous OR in an asynchronous way. Depending on this option the behaviour of the task changes dramatically.

Comment: By Asnychronous do you mean that one row of input is not equivalent to one row of output?  this concept within the concept of Script tasks and components has always confused me.  What do synchronous and asynchronous mean within the context of this component?

Comment: Synchronous (1:1): Every input row is transformed / used and the resulting row goes to the output. Asynchronous (m:n): Read as many input rows as you want and send as many rows as you want to the output. Example: Imagine an Excel file, in which every row contains parameters for a web service call. You would use a synchronous task, if the web service delivers one row as a result for that Excel-row's parameters. But if you get n rows from the web service, you would use an asynchronous task, so that you can get all those rows to the output (instead of just one).

Comment: ok my solution is this; the flat file has the primary keys of records in the table to be searched, in the test file I have 3 records in the flat file.  The output will ultimately return 3 records as well, but with plenty more fields.  So I guess it is synchronous  The SDK being accessed however is most efficiently run in a batch statement; gathering all the records' primary keys at the same time and then returning the data in a single output, instead of accessing that information for each row.  So would that make it asynchronous?

Comment: Yep, that would be asynchronous (despite the n:n relation). if speed matters, then you should do it that way.

Comment: Ok I found the issue.  No records were transmitting because an issue with a leading space in the records being searched in the external sdk.  The fields were coming from a csv file so I overlooked it, but once I was able to step through the code, I found the error.